# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method set_logger(Lorg/koin/core/logger/Logger;)V in class Lorg/koin/core/Koin; or its super classes

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, viewmodel, coroutine

please help me for solve this error, I'm already dizzy because this error has not been resolved

```
    startKoin {
        androidLogger(Level.ERROR)
        androidContext(this@IHSAplication)
        androidFileProperties()
        modules(commonModule, viewModelModule)
    }
```